# Excel to access file data tranfer by SQL server

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sql-server, microsoft-access

I have an issue While Transfer Data From Ms Excel to MS Access by SQL Server

here is my program

```
 Public Sub DoTrans()
DoEvents
Sheets("Temp").Select
  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  'dbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Database2021.mdb"
  dbPath = "\\datasource\Temp\Database2021.mdb"
 dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
 dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
  scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
  dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
  cn.Open scn

  ssql = "INSERT INTO Table1 ([DataEnteredOn],[Date],[DATA],[EstimatedHours],[ActualHours],[Eff%],[Remarks],[ESR#] ) "
  'ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

  ssql = ssql & "SELECT [DataEnteredOn],[Date],[DATA],[EstimatedHours],[ActualHours],[Eff%],[Remarks],[ESR#]  FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh
  cn.Execute ssql
  cn.Close
  
  Sheets("Temp").Select
    
   MsgBox "Your datas saved. If you want to check, Please click ""Complete Database"" button"

Call CLEARDATA

End Sub
```

INPUT IS **0.117**

BUT OUTPUT IS **0.110**

I NEED TO FIX the Data Conversion.

Refer the Below Snap, i try to adjust the Decimal places. But its not work

[image: INPUT FROM MS EXCEL]

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE FROM ACCESS]

[image: DECIMAL PLACES 3 IN EXCEL]

[image: DECIMAL PLACES 3 IN ACCESS]

Comment: Anyone understand my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale and decimal place must be equal then our input and output will be same.